# Accessing a Web Database using a Local Application

Tags: c#, mysql, web-applications, web, desktop-application

We're currently developing a desktop Application using C# and we've created a local database using MySQL.

Now are trying to create a desktop application that can access a web database but we don't know what to do.

1) Is it possible to create a desktop application that can do that just by using C#?

2) How can we convert or connect a local database to the internet?

3) What language do we need to learn?

Comment: _Is it possible to create a desktop application that can do that just by using C#?_ Yes. _How can we convert or connect a local database to the internet?_ We need more details about your problem. _what do language do we need to learn?_ This is totally depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand correctly the application needs to collect data from a web service. Not having much experience with C# tho it sounds like you need a database, web server and the client application (which you have already).

### 1) Is it possible to create a desktop application that can do that just by using C#?

Yes, it is. You could write a server socket program in C# and connect to it using your client application ([inspiration](http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-server-socket.htm))

### 2) How can we convert or connect a local database to the internet?

You could setup a MySQL server ([netbeans](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/install-and-configure-mysql-server.html) example). Or simply connect the server socket program from above to the database (take a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43438/Connect-C-to-MySQL)).

### 3) what do language do we need to learn?

Seems like you have what you need in C# and SQL to complete the task.

My advice is to continue in the following order:

1. Write the Server app, so it responds with some dummy data
2. Modify your client app to connect to the server and successfully receive data
3. Once (2) is complete modify the server to connect to the database